# Mysql: Get latest row by two dates

Tags: mysql, join

May be someone could give me an advice how to achieve my goal.
I'm using MySQL

I have a table with historical data

```
CREATE TABLE `history` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `from_dt` date NOT NULL,
    `date_create` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `approved` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
    KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
)
```

Is there easier way to get dataset with latest records for each user(user_id) in this table, where `from_dt` less than `now()`

`from_dt` - could contain any date, so there're might be records in the future and in the past.

What I got for now:

```
SELECT * FROM `history` right join (SELECT 
    history.user_id, MAX(date_create)
FROM
    history
        RIGHT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        user_id, MAX(from_dt) max_from
    FROM
        history
    WHERE
        from_dt < NOW()
    GROUP BY user_id , from_dt) AS hf ON hf.max_from = history.from_dt
        AND hf.user_id = history.user_id
GROUP BY user_id) as hdt on hdt.user_id = history.user_id
```

But join tables 3 times to itself looks a little bit messy for me, cause I have to join here additional data (like user info, etc)

Many thanks,
Max

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this -

```
SELECT *
FROM `history` H1
INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id, MAX(from_dt) max_from
            FROM history
            GROUP BY user_id) users
ON H1.`date_create` = users.max_from
WHERE from_dt < NOW()
```

Comment: I forgot to say, sorry, `from_dt` is not unique, so there're might be multiple records with same `from_dt` and `user_id` but different `date_create`, also I guess this `H1.`date_create` = users.max_from` expression is not correct, it might be like that `H1.`from_dt` = users.max_from`